# Google Sheets Auto Categorize Budget from Statement

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Categories sheet and a Statement sheet. The Categories sheet contains a list of all possible categories, and the Statement sheet is an export of my credit card. How can I automatically categorize the purchases based on keywords within the description?

Categories Example:

[image]

Statement Example:
[image]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: You'd typically use regex  with `REGEXMATCH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` and `search()` or `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=+filter(Categories!B$2:B, search(Categories!A$2:A, E2))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [search()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154) and [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).